# Why doesn't my Jsoup Maven project run?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, dependencies, jsoup

Hi I am new to Maven and JSoup and trying to run an example in Intellij so I can get an understanding of JSoup.

I added the dependencies of JSoup to my POM.xml file. I pushed to Github when the project was working. As soon as I pulled from Github the project won't run. So I went into the terminal and getting JSoup errors that certain imports don't exist. I tried to 'run' as a Maven project but now I'm even more confused.

Please see the image below which demonstrates the file structure. The code is simple its the config / setup that I am really struggling with.

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ng94z.png)

The POM.xml content is seen below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>WebScraper</groupId>
<artifactId>WebScraper</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <!-- jsoup HTML parser library @ http://jsoup.org/ -->
                <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
                <version>1.10.2</version>
            </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Hopefully someone can help with this.

Thanks

Comment: You did not import the project from `pom.xml`. Therefore source roots are not defined and no dependencies are added to the project. Use Import from the Welcome screen and select `pom.xml` file, overwrite existing project files when asked.

Comment: I reopened the project and noticed a box in the right hand corner asking if I wanted to build a Maven project and it now works. So the problem was if i pull from GitHub the build will not also be imported? I have to add the build tool after its been pulled?
Thanks

Comment: It depends on what you share on github, see https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544839. Normally you need to import from `pom.xml` anyway.